# Two headings with same markup are rendered differently

Tags: html, css, iframe

On a website that i help manage we just implemented an iframe which handles requests sent to our company.

The site uses the following css for its headings:

```
color: #222;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: normal;
text-decoration: none;
font-family: Carrois Gothic,sans-serif;
line-height: 120%;
margin-top: 5px;
```

I implemented the exact same markup for the headings in the iframe, but they are rendered differently, can anyone explain why, and possibly how to fix the issue?

Url of site: http://mentordanmark.dk/lektiehjaelp-folkeskolen, iframe is the bottom most heading, the difference is clear with letters like capital V.

Comment: Link your *Google Font* in your `iframe` also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to reference the google font stylesheet in your document head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to partypete25 i figured out the issue, which was google fonts.

This made the font work on my local machine, but not in the live website. After tinkering around myself i found that adding https to the link solved the issue, and i ended up adding the following code to my iframes.

```
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carrois+Gothic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

It's likely my server that didnt allow contacting the unencrypted version, but that might happen to someone else as well.